# When I call my tasks to add to the list it print "bound dispatchSetState" into the UI instead of the tasks [React]

Tags: reactjs

I think I am misunderstanding something behind this which I need understanding. here's a photo of the problem. Task does not render to the UI, instead it renders "bound dispatchSetState". Here is also the code.[image: UI problem tasks does not render properly]

```
    function App(props) {
  
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(props.tasks)

function addTask (name){
  
  const newTask = {
    id: 'todo-' + nanoid(),
    name: name,
    completed: false
   };
    setTasks([...tasks, setTasks]);
  
  }

const taskList = tasks.map(task => (
  <Todo  
  id={task.id} 
  name={task.name} 
  completed={task.completed}
  key={task.id}
  />
  ));
```

Here is my app.js code Above.
Here is how my form is handling the submission Below.

```
export default function Form(props) {

    const [name, setName] = useState(' ')

    function handleChange(e){
      setName(e.target.value)
    }


    function  handleSubmit (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        props.addTask(name);
        setName(" ") ;
      

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I looked over it aprox. 1 minute after I posted this and I made an typo error on the object on the end of the array. Instead of "setTasks" I'm adding a new task so I should put "newTask" which is the name i've assigned the object as.

The error occurs in my app.js